# Override $scheme in nginx When Behind Load Balancer

Tags: nginx, ssl, load-balancing

I've got an nginx server sitting behind a load balancer. The load balancer handles SSL termination with all requests hitting nginx on port 80. I'm also using the [SRCache module](https://github.com/openresty/srcache-nginx-module) for full page caching using Redis. The caching module uses the URL as a cache key like `$schemeGET$host$request_uri`. I was thinking I could just override nginx's `$scheme` variable somehow so the cache key scheme would be `https` instead of `http` I'm not sure how to do that or if it is even possible.

My app does cache purging after various events and it generates the cache key using `https` but nginx is caching using `http` in the cache key. This means the cache is not purged properly due to the missmatched cache key names.

Here is my site configuration if that helps:

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name example.com example.org example.net ;

set $redirect_to_https 0;
if ( $http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https' ) {
  set $redirect_to_https 1;
}
if ( $request_uri = '/health-check.php' ) {
  set $redirect_to_https 0;
}
if ( $redirect_to_https = 1 ) {
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# Uncomment the following line for domain mapping
server_name_in_redirect off;

access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log rt_cache_redis;
error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;


root /var/www/example.com/htdocs;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

include  common/redis-php7.conf;

include common/wpcommon-php7-modified.conf;
include common/locations-php7.conf;
include /var/www/example.com/conf/nginx/*.conf;
}
```

UPDATE Here is the caching configuration

```
# Redis NGINX CONFIGURATION
# DO NOT MODIFY, ALL CHANGES LOST AFTER UPDATE EasyEngine (ee)
set $skip_cache 0;
# POST requests and URL with a query string should always go to php
if ($request_method = POST) {
  set $skip_cache 0;
}
if ($query_string != "") {
  set $skip_cache 1;
}
# Don't cache URL containing the following segments
if ($request_uri ~* "(/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|index.php|/feed/|sitemap(_index)?.xml|[a-z0-9_-]+-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml)") {
  set $skip_cache 1;
}
# Don't use the cache for logged in users or recent commenter
if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
  set $skip_cache 1;
}
# Use cached or actual file if they exists, Otherwise pass request to WordPress
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location /redis-fetch {
    internal  ;
    set  $redis_key $args;
    redis_pass  redis;
}
location /redis-store {
    internal  ;
    set_unescape_uri $key $arg_key ;
    redis2_query  set $key $echo_request_body;
    redis2_query expire $key 14400;
    redis2_pass  redis;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
  set $key "nginx-cache:$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
  try_files $uri =404;

  srcache_fetch_skip $skip_cache;
  srcache_store_skip $skip_cache;

  srcache_response_cache_control off;

  set_escape_uri $escaped_key $key;

  srcache_fetch GET /redis-fetch $key;
  srcache_store PUT /redis-store key=$escaped_key;

  more_set_headers 'X-SRCache-Fetch-Status $srcache_fetch_status';
  more_set_headers 'X-SRCache-Store-Status $srcache_store_status';

  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_pass php7;
}
```

Comment: This might be possible using Nginx, but I can't personally see how. Altering your app is possibly the easiest solution, or changing the source of the module. You could terminate SSL with Nginx, but that's a potentially significant architecture change.

Comment: @tim Yea I think changing it in the app is the way to go here. I thought this might be easy to do via nginx. Oh well...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, so here we see your cache key that is being used for redis lookups:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  set $key "nginx-cache:$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
```

The problem is that `$scheme` reflects the connection that was made to nginx (from your load balancer), but your caching module is using the scheme from `$http_x_forwarded_proto`, which reflects the actual scheme in use.

It should be sufficient to just make that change.