# nginx try_files issuing http redirect beind load balancer; need https

Tags: nginx, ssl, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, 301-redirect

My nginx instance is behind a SSL terminated load balancer, and I want all urls to hit `https` endpoints, which means `http` to be redirected to `https`.

All is well when urls have a trailing slash. They all get redirected nicely:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

do_curl() {
   echo "\n$ do_curl $1"
   curl -L -s -D - "$1" -o /dev/null | grep -iE 'Location|HTTP/|server'
}

$ do_curl https://example.com/
HTTP/2 200

$ do_curl http://example.com/foo/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://example.com/foo/
HTTP/2 200

$ do_curl https://example.com/foo/
HTTP/2 200
```

But when the same urls have no trailing slash, nginx's `try_files` seems to be issuing a `http` redirect always:
[bad.png](https://i.postimg.cc/RhHbsYFG/2.png)

Here's my nginx `vhost.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /app/;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # This 'if' block is only needed because my SSL-terminated Load balancer proxies both http and https to nginx.
    # If my Load balancer only proxied https to nginx, and dropped http, this 'if' block can be omitted.
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

How do I get nginx's `try_files` to redirect directly with the `https` `$scheme` when it hits the `$uri/` parameter (2nd parameter in my `try_files` above) and successfully finds a file matching `$uri/<index>` (where `index` is defined by the `index` directive in the nginx config above)?

I searched similar questions such as [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/678342/nginx-try-files-redirect-using-wrong-scheme-when-behind-ssl-termination-load-bal), [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/449036/how-do-i-get-nginx-to-issue-301-requests-to-https-location-when-ssl-handled-by), or [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/823752/override-scheme-in-nginx-when-behind-load-balancer) but still could not find anything remotely relevant.

Comment: ```try_files``` will never *redirect*, it will always *rewrite*. That ```server``` you defined is listening on *http*. Make it always redirect using ```return```. Define another ```server``` that listens on *https*.

Comment: thanks @RichardSmith. That link answered it. I posted an answer explaining the nature of my question, and how your answer in that link had the solution I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Florin pointed out in the comments of the question, `try_files` only performs rewrites. So I went back and omitted the `try_files` block in my `vhost.conf` and true enough, I got back the very same behavior where `https` urls with **no trailing slash** get redirected to its `http` **trailed** counterpart.

## Solution

Instead, my question title should have been more like 'How to prevent nginx redirecting from HTTPS to HTTP', which would then be a duplicate question of [How to prevent nginx redirecting from HTTPS to HTTP on AWS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/885046/how-to-prevent-nginx-redirecting-from-https-to-http-on-aws) that @Richard pointed out in his comment on my question, and which he answered.

Coincidentally, **my circumstances and question are in fact identical to those in that question**. In his answer, @Richard points out that the best way to mitigate the problem where nginx assumes the same `$scheme` as the requester (i.e. SSL terminated Load balancer) would be to do a  replacement of `http` with `https` in the `Location` header at the point of the Load balancer, which was not possible for me. He then goes on to describe *three* ways when performing redirects where the `$scheme` would be `https`.

Of the three solutions, the one that worked for me was to use `absolute_redirect off;`. This prevented nginx from using the wrong `$scheme` that it used in redirects.

Now, my `vhost.conf` would just have to be:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /app/;
    index index.html index.htm;

    absolute_redirect off;

    # This 'if' block is only needed because my SSL-terminated Load balancer proxies both http and https to nginx.
    # If my Load balancer only proxied https to nginx, and dropped http, this 'if' block can be omitted.
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```